# Jinja2, depending on the condition return value or the original string?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

Let's have the following code:

```
{{snippet ('name' cache=True)}}
```

If the cache is true, then return the result, if the cache is not true then return the original string:

```
{{snippet ('name' cache=True)}}
```

How can I implement it? Thanks to all who will respond.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? It would help if you show the code in question.

Comment: I need to understand how to get the source code line {{snippet ('name' cache = True)}}

The rest is clear as to intercept ... I do not quite understand what code is needed in this situation?